# How to validate a string is combined by year and week number in c#?

Tags: c#

**How to check a string is combined by year and week number by c# code?**

Like `"202153"`,here "53" is the 53th week in 2021,and the week number cannot over 53 in 2021,
so,`"202154"` is not valid.

---

Thanks everyone for your suggestions, this is indeed an ambiguous question.I confirmed with my leader that our current system only needs to consider that the number of weeks does not exceed 53.

Comment: Would `54` _ever_ be valid for _any_ year?

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: 1) Use `Substring` and create two strings: one that contains the year, and one that contains the week. 2) Parse them as integers. 3) Perform any validation logic you need re year/week combinations.

Comment: And as a first step, validate that the string has exactly 6 digits and possibly always starts with "20" or maybe also with "19" (depending on the range of years supported)

Comment: `202153` could be interpreted as the third week of the year 20215 though. There are also ambiguities such as `202111`. It could mean week 11 of 2021, or week 1 of 20211. This format is not very well-defined. I suggest that you add more constraints to the format.

Comment: @mjwills https://www.allegro.com/papers/54.html

Comment: @FranzGleichmann That is why I am asking - to tease out _what_ they mean. Knowing whether they think 54 is a possible valid answer will help us narrow down the solution to the problem. The fact that there are _two_ answers already that didn't consider this possibility means it is key we know more to answer the question accurately.

Comment: 2021 has 52 weeks not 53, google "weeks in year 2021"

Answer (score 1):

try this. you can change last line as per logic.

```
string date1 = "202154";

int year = Convert.ToInt32(date1.Substring(0, 4));
int weekNo = Convert.ToInt32(date1.Substring(4, 2));


//Validate week
DateTimeFormatInfo dfi = DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo;
DateTime date = new DateTime(year, 12, 31);//Get last date of year
Calendar cal = dfi.Calendar;
int weekOfYear = cal.GetWeekOfYear(date, dfi.CalendarWeekRule, dfi.FirstDayOfWeek);//Get last week of the year.

 bool answer = weekNo > weekOfYear?false:true;
```

Comment: So this outputs false for weeks smaller than the last week of the year?

Comment: in the question it was compared with last week. If required last line can be modified as per the logic change.